# Modern language that can be compiled to DLL and can be used in Linux web server back-end?

Tags: c#, c++, python, linux, excel

I plan to write a program with the following prerequisites:

1. Must be able to be compiled to DLL, to be able to run functions from an Excel workbook (legacy compatibility)
2. As modern, high-level and fast as develop in as possible.
3. The same functions must be able to be called in a Linux web server backend (the frontend will be written in Javascript).
4. Compiler must be free as in beer.

Is there a language that is compliant with all three requirements? I have looked at:

- **Python:** does 2) and 3), but no good solutions for 1). There is a translator from Python to C++ at http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/, but it is experimental.
- **C++:** Does 1) but not 2), and is not really ideal for 3).
- **C#:** Does 1) and 2), but not 3) to my knowledge.

I know how to run an exe file from Excel, so I can solve it that way, but a DLL would be a better solution for two reasons:

1. I can call methods directly without going via the command line, and
2. my users are more likely to be suspicious if I include a .exe file with the application than if I include a .dll file. (I know there is no real difference, but my users do not.)

Thanks!

Comment: Note that Python is a scripting language, and thus does not compile to DLLs but instead you distribute the source and run in it in the interpreter. Where does your DLL requirement come from? If you're concerned about portability/distributability,there are methods for scripting languages too.

Comment: I know I can make Python code portable by using py2exe, but a DLL would be superior for two reasons: 1) I can call methods directly without going via the command line, and 2) my users are likely more suspicious if I include a .exe file with the application than if I include a .dll file. Superstitious, I know. Exe is my backup solution, but I want to know if there is any solution that I haven't thought of

Comment: good reasons. Just wanted to make sure you are aware.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I needed to clarify that, I updated the question.

Comment: Java? you can compile it using `gcj`

Comment: gcj can not compile to DLL, can it? At least I couldn't find anything with a Google search. Please answer and provide a reference if you can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> C#: Does 1) and 2), but not 3) to my knowledge.

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) (non-Microsoft, open-source, cross-platform CLI implementation) works on linux, and can be used for a web-server.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best choice under the circumstances.